# Dokku (Digital Ocean) client_max_body_size node.js

Tags: node.js, nginx, digital-ocean, dokku

So I've just pushed my app to Dokku (Digital Ocean) - and get the following error returned from an ajax post:

POST http://example.com/foo 413 (Request Entity Too Large)

A quick google shows this problem is due to client_max_body_size being too low. So I've SSH'd into the server, opened up the apps nginx.conf and increased it as per instructions here:

```
client_max_body_size 100M;
```

https://github.com/progrium/dokku/issues/802

However, I still have the same problem... Do I need to restart a process or something? I tried restarting the dokku app - but all this did was to overwrite my nginx.conf file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has been updated in Dokku and can be done from the CLI: `dokku nginx:set node-js-app client-max-body-size 50m`. https://dokku.com/docs/networking/proxies/nginx/#specifying-a-custom-client_max_body_size

Answer (score 16):

@Rob s answer is correct, but has the problem that the changes are not persisted, because the nginx.conf might become regenerated e.g. when deploying.

The solution I use is outlined in this github commit https://github.com/econya/dokku/commit/d4ea8520ac3c9e90238e75866906a5d834539129 .

Basically, dokkus default nginx templates include every file in the `nginx.conf.d/` subfolder into the main `server` configuration block, thus

```
mkdir /home/dokku/myapp/nginx.conf.d/
echo 'client_max_body_size 50M;' > /home/dokku/myapp/nginx.conf.d/upload.conf
chown dokku:dokku /home/dokku/myapp/nginx.conf.d/upload.conf
service nginx reload
```

Will create a file that is merged into the `nginx.conf` (at nginx startup time I believe) and kept untouched by `dokku` as long as you do not use interfering plugins or define another nginx template (as of 2017/08).

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out - I had to cd into the apps directory (as per github instructions:  https://github.com/progrium/dokku/issues/802

> The right file to modify is /home/dokku//nginx.conf and as @dipankar mentioned, you should add a client_max_body_size 20M; line to the server scope.

and then I typed

```
reload nginx
```

into the command line. All works :)

Comment: If anyone knows how I can persist these settings between deploys - that would be great!

Comment: See my answer above ;)